# Docker内のアプリにPCから接続できない

Tags: linux, docker

VirtulBox上にCentOSをインストールし、CentOS内でDockerを動かしております。
以下の様なDockerfile作成後、ビルド→docker runを実行しましたが、ローカルPC（ホストPC）のブラウザから
Docker内のアプリにアクセスしましたが接続できない状況です。

原因を調べてみると、ポートフォーワーディングの設定が必要とのことで以下のポートフォワーディングの設定を行いました。
・ホストOSとVirtulBoxの5000ポートを紐づけ
・VirtulBoxとコンテナの5000ポートの紐づけ

上記の設定を行っても、ローカルPCのブラウザから
Docker内のアプリにアクセスしましたが接続できず困っております。

どなたかアドバイスの程、よろしくお願い致します。

```
FROM ubuntu:bionic

RUN apt update -y && apt install -y python3-pip python-dev

# ローカルにあるファイルをコンテナ内にコピー
COPY ./requirements.txt requirements.txt

RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

# 現在のディレクトリにあるファイル一覧をコンテナ内にコピーする
COPY . .

# 実行コマンド
ENTRYPOINT ["python3"]

# 上記に対する引数(python3 app.pyが実行される)
CMD ["app.py"]
```

```
FROM ubuntu:bionic

RUN apt update -y && apt install -y python3-pip python-dev

# ローカルにあるファイルをコンテナ内にコピー
COPY ./requirements.txt requirements.txt

RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

# 現在のディレクトリにあるファイル一覧をコンテナ内にコピーする
COPY . .

# 実行コマンド
ENTRYPOINT ["python3"]

# 上記に対する引数(python3 app.pyが実行される)
CMD ["app.py"]
```

ビルド実行

```
docker build -t my_flask .
```

```
# 実行結果
[+] Building 1.6s (10/10) FINISHED
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                       0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 549B                                       0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                          0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                            0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/ubuntu:bionic           1.4s
 => [1/5] FROM docker.io/library/ubuntu:bionic@sha256:8aa9c2798215f99544d  0.0s
 => [internal] load build context                                          0.0s
 => => transferring context: 423B                                          0.0s
 => CACHED [2/5] RUN apt update -y && apt install -y python3-pip python-d  0.0s
 => CACHED [3/5] COPY ./requirements.txt requirements.txt                  0.0s
 => CACHED [4/5] RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt                      0.0s
 => [5/5] COPY . .                                                         0.0s
 => exporting to image                                                     0.0s
 => => exporting layers                                                    0.0s
 => => writing image sha256:e0a22348a4d5f0358d482a71115172622ce66604ab0cf  0.0s
 => => naming to docker.io/library/my_flask                                0.0s
[root@localhost flask_app]#
```

イメージの確認

```
REPOSITORY   TAG       IMAGE ID       CREATED              SIZE
my_flask     latest    e0a22348a4d5   About a minute ago   562MB
```

コンテナ起動

```
docker run -it e0a22348a4d5
```

起動結果メッセージ

```
* Serving Flask app "app" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
 * Running on all addresses.
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
 * Running on http://172.17.0.2:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

自分のPCから、http://172.17.0.2:5000/へアクセスしても、
このサイトにアクセスできません。172.17.0.2 からの応答時間が長すぎます。となってしまいます。

Comment: 「VirtualBox 上で Docker」を動かしているのは何か理由がありますか？構成が複雑になるほど躓くポイントが増えるので、可能ならば簡単な構成を検討すべきです。 (ホスト OS 上で直接 Docker を動かすでは NG なのか)

Answer (score 0):

### 回答

こちらの環境でも似たような現象が発生しました。
最初はapp.runの実引数を`app.run(debug=True)`としていましたが、
`app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=5000, debug=True)`にすることにより現象は解消しました。

---

こちらの環境ではDockerを動かすOracle VirtualBoxのVMにはネットワークアドレス`192.168.200.0`に属する固定IPを設定しています。
今回は`192.168.200.115`です。
ネットワークアドレス192.168.200.0に属するIPをホストオンリーアダプタにルーティングすることによってホストPCでのリクエストをVMにとばしています。
ホストPCは業務のネットワークに接続することもあるため、ブリッジは使っていません。ホストPC内に閉じたネットワークを構成して動作確認を行っています。

---

### ファイル

- Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:bionic
RUN apt update -y && apt install -y python3-pip python-dev
# ローカルにあるファイルをコンテナ内にコピー
COPY ./requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
# 現在のディレクトリにあるファイル一覧をコンテナ内にコピーする
COPY . .
# 実行コマンド
ENTRYPOINT ["python3"]
# 上記に対する引数(python3 app.pyが実行される)
CMD ["app.py"]
```

- requirements.txt

```
flask
```

- app.py

```
from flask import Flask,render_template
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello World"
@app.route("/index")
def index():
    return render_template("index.html")
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # app.run(debug=True)
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=5000, debug=True)
```

---

#### Dockerの操作

- ビルド

```
docker build -t my_flask .
```

- 起動

```
docker run -p 5000:5000 -it my_flask
```

```
 * Serving Flask app 'app' (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: on
 * Running on all addresses.
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
 * Running on http://172.17.0.2:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
 * Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 586-744-614
```

---

#### Oracle VM VirtualBoxマネージャーの設定

- ファイル - ツール - Network Manager

  - VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter

    - IPv4
      192.168.200.1
    - IPv4ネットマスク
      255.255.0.0
- ノード選択 - 設定 - ネットワーク

  - アダプタ1
    NATネットワーク
  - アダプタ2
    ホストオンリーアダプタ

---

#### VM(OS:CentOS Stream 9)の設定

- IP(enp0s8) 固定IP
  inet 192.168.200.115/24

---

#### ホスト(OS:Win10)の設定

- ルーティング設定

```
route add -p 192.168.200.0/24 192.168.200.1
```

---

#### 実行結果(ホストPC)

```
>curl 192.168.200.115:5000
Hello World
```

Answer (score -2):

まずは、VirtualBoxのネットワークをブリッジとしましょう
それで、ゲストは、ホストのネットワークに直接接続される形となります。